# Matlab-How can I extract features from an image using Partial Least Square (PLS) regression?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, computer-vision, regression

Can anyone help me to understand how can I extract features from an image using [Partial least squares (PLS) regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_least_squares_regression) function ["plsregress()"](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/plsregress.html) in Matlab?

Before this, I have used PCA function in Matlab "princomp()" to extract features from the image, what I have understood is, for example if we have 20 images, each one 50×50pixels. The first step is

(1) construct the input matrix, where each row represent one image, that is mean the size of the input matrix is [20 , 50×50] = [20,2500].

(2) when we call the pca() in matlab we get:

[eigenvectors score variances] = princomp(inputMatrix);

the eigenvectors which represent the Principle components' coefficients (features) , the score of the Principal components and the variances (eigenvalues) of each principal component.

(3) To construct the dataset in the test stage, I have used the a test dataset which is a matrix consist of one image, its size is [50,50] and I have used the principal components ( eigenvectors) with the higher variances (for example the first 5 components) to reconstruct the dataset.

First, I have used this equation to calculate the score of test dataset

test_score = test_dataset * eigenvalues(: ,1:5);

newtest_data = test_score * eigenvalues(:, 1:5)' ; // reconstructing dataset using 5 PCs.

***My question is,  how can I perform same steps but by using Partial Least Square (PLS) regression?***

Comment: It would help if you told us what "Partial" Least Square regression was.  I really have no idea.

Comment: @rayryeng, I have provided links in the description.